# Trouble dereferencing ip and port from socket pointer

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, p2p

I'm doing a simple send/receive and in order to execute each request in a thread I've set up my handler function like so:

**UPDATE: Using std::thread and properly closing socket after use. I'm not using a loop for reading atm because I'm just sending small test messages that are well below the 1024 buffer limit. Unfortunately, I'm still getting odd data for the ip and port.**

```c
int P2PServer::socketReceiveHandler(int s) {
    struct sockaddr_in *sin = (struct sockaddr_in *)&s;
    
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    int reader;
    reader = read(s, buffer, 1024);
    if (reader <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        std::cout << reader << std::endl; // let's see
    }

    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int port=0;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sin->sin_addr), ip, sizeof(ip));
    port = htons(sin->sin_port);
    strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(sin->sin_addr));
    printf ("Connection from %s:%d\n", ip, port);

    printf("Connection from: %d.%d.%d.%d", buffer[197], buffer[198], buffer[199], buffer[200]);
    //int port = 0;                         // Start with zero
    port |= buffer[204] & 0xFF;             // Assign first byte to port using bitwise or.
    port <<= 8;                             // Shift the bits left by 8 
    port |= buffer[205] & 0xFF;             // (so the byte from before is on the correct position)
    printf(" Port: %d\n\n", port);


    char const* message = "I am an amazing server!";
    std::cout << "received: " << buffer << std::endl; 
    send(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 );
    printf("Server : Message has been sent ! \n");

    if (close(s) == -1) {
        p2putils::logit("Close problems");
        std::cout << "errno: " << errno << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The function is called like so:

```c
std::thread peerThread (&P2PServer::socketReceiveHandler,this, incomingSocket);
peerThread.join();
```

Here's the output from the server:

```
./p2pserver 127.0.0.1 10001
Node usage for peers: ./p2pserver <ip> <port> <masternode>
If this is not the master node, restart with 3rd parameter
P2P Server: 127.0.0.1 is listening on PORT: 10001
 

Waiting for incoming connections...
23
Connection from 8.233.176.178:0
Connection from: 0.0.0.0 Port: 0

received: I am an amazing client.
Server : Message has been sent ! 
 

Waiting for incoming connections...
```

Here's the output from the client:

```
./p2pserver 127.0.0.1 10002 127.0.0.1
P2P Server: 127.0.0.1 is listening on PORT: 10002
Client : Message has been sent ! 
I am an amazing server!
 

Waiting for incoming connections...
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)? That will make it easier (trivial really) to use non-static member functions. And you won't have to worry about possible data-races which you likely have by passing a pointer to the socket descriptor, as with `std::thread` you can pass arguments by value.

Comment: As for the transmission and the socket handling. You really need to add error checking for the `read` call. It can fail, or it can return `0` to indicate connection closed. And if it's a TCP socket there's no guarantee that a single `read` call will actually receive everything, you need to use a loop to be able to read the full message (and have a protocol that have message boundaries).

Comment: Also, who has the responsibility to `close` the socket once you're done with it? Are you using the socket outside the thread you show? That's a data-race. And if you don't `close` the socket you have a resource leak.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _That's a data-race_ Aren't sockets threadsafe?

Comment: @PaulSanders Not really no. As TCP sockets are streaming receive calls in different threads could receive partial data, and there's a real chance that none of the threads receive a full message.

Comment: To the OP (Sonny Parlin): Check what `read` returns! I'll bet that it returns a value less than `197`.

Comment: I'm new to C++ this is a ton of info, thank you, I'll do some more research. Especially on std::thread.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the suggestions, I've updated the question with new code. Still running into the same issue receiving the connected ip and port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the function that saved the day is getpeername()

Here's my working solution:

```c
int P2PServer::socketReceiveHandler(int s) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    int reader;
    reader = read(s, buffer, 1024);
    if (reader <= 0)
        return 0;

    socklen_t len;
    len = sizeof(addr);
    getpeername(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
    std::cout << "Connection from: " 
              << inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr) 
              << " : " 
              << ntohs(addr.sin_port) << std::endl;

    char const* message = "I am an amazing server!";
    std::cout << "received: " << buffer << std::endl; 
    send(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 );
    printf("Server : Message has been sent ! \n");

    if (close(s) == -1) {
        p2putils::logit("Close problems");
        std::cout << "errno: " << errno << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The partial output is as follows:

```
P2P Server: 127.0.0.1 is listening on PORT: 10001
 

Waiting for incoming connections...
Connection from: 127.0.0.1 : 58560
```